# How Can I print The number of Factor of a Number without there factors please have a look on my code

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int N,i;
    int count=0;
    cin>>N;

    for(i=1;i<=N;i++){
        if(N%i==0){
            cout<<i<<" ";
            count++;
        }
  
    }

}
```

INPUT 6

OUTPUT 1 2 3 6
4

I want to print the Number of Factors which is 4 in this case Before the Factors. I did it few days ago but i forget that now please help me..

Comment: Why have you tagged this C? Also perhaps spend a little time formatting the question

Comment: Just print `count` outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want by putting the factors in the array.
like:
int k =0 ;
arr[k++] = i;

now,
first print the count and then traverse and print the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cout on line 12 and it will work fine :). That is printing the "i" which are the numbers you don't need.

```
cout<<i<<" ";
```

This line remove it.

Edit: I reread and found that you wanted to print the factors after it. You could save it in a vector or an array.

```
#include <vector> // At the top of your program
```

```
std::vector<int> factors; // At the declaration step
```

```
factors.push_back(i); // Where your cout << "i" initially was
```

```
// After the cout of your count
for ( auto &factor : factors ){
    std::cout << factor << " ";
}
```

Comment: actually i wanted to print this code without using any data structures like array or vector i did it few days ago that thing is out of my mind now